# Asana API: How do I remove a parent from a subtask with the new setParent endpoint

Tags: asana

According to the Asana API documentation it should be possible to remove a parent from a subtask, so the subtask becomes a normal task:

> Creating a subtask is the same as a creating an normal task, but instead of specifying a workspace you must specify a parent task. Each task can only have a single parent and you can use the setParent endpoint to add or remove a parent from an existing task.

However it's not clear to me how i can remove a parent with this endpoint. 
I've tried the following things as the body of the request

```
parent=0
```

=> 400 bad request
{"errors":[{"message":"parent: Not an ID: 0"}]}

```
null
```

=> 400 bad request
{"errors":[{"message":"Could not parse request data, invalid JSON"}]}

```
parent={subtaskid}
```

=> 500 error (makes sense that you can't add a subtask as parent of itself, but shouldn't be a 500 error I think)
    {"errors":[{"message":"Server Error","phrase":"14 orange apes run smoothly"}]}

```
parent=
```

=> 400 bad request
{"errors":[{"message":"parent: Not an ID: "}]}

Is this at all possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I work at Asana.) Have you tried `parent=null`?

Comment: That works, thanks! Might be good to mention this on the api doc page as well?